# Can I go through a recruiter if I've applied directly to the same company before?

Tags: recruitment

I applied directly to a company but received no response. However as it was online I'm now on their database.

Can I still go through a recruitment agency for the same company but a different role?

I'm worried that because I'm already on the company database I can't go through a recruiter for the same company. Even though I received no response from the company directly and it is for a different role.

Please let me know your views.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: How long ago? Typically companies keep your resume in their system for several months. This is definitely something you would want to mention to the recruiter before they submit you, as they may refuse to represent you to the client

Comment: About two months ago. Can you see this being an issue?

Comment: Also the role I applied for was permanent. And the role via recruiter is a contact role.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points telling me that you are okay to go through the recruiter.

First, you went directly to the company first and *then* to the recruiter, not the other way around. Most examples of unprofessional behavior in situations like this are because someone applied through a recruiter and then went around them to apply directly. This violates an agreement with the recruiter, written or non-written, and is almost always viewed negatively if the company realizes you've done it. For you there's no representation agreement to break, so there's nothing wrong.

Second, the position through the recruiter is as a contractor, not direct hire. This implies to me that your employer will actually be a separate contracting agency, not the company you have previously applied to.

As mentioned in [a comment above](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/85168/can-i-go-through-a-recruiter-if-ive-applied-directly-to-the-same-company-before#comment244297_85168), definitely still tell your recruiter that you have previously applied to the company, as it may be useful for them to know. But otherwise you should be fine, so good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My experience in the past answers this question in the negative, at least in Florida.

A recruiter has to have what they call "right to represent", which can only be assigned to them if you haven't already applied to a given employer in the past six months. Why should the employer pay a recruiter to hire you if you've already applied to their company - even if they've already overlooked you!

The recruiter can still pitch you, but since they don't have right to represent, they won't get anything out of placing you and will probably drop you for that position. Generally, they ask if you've every applied to a company before they start shopping your resume around, but this could be a regional thing.